# What's the difference between using IList, IEnumerable, ISet or ICollection in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, parent-child

What's the difference between using `IList`, `IEnumerable`, `ISet` or `ICollection` for collections of child objects in NHibernate's entities classes? I.e:

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual int IdParent { set; get; }

    public virtual IList<Child> Children { set; get; }
    // Or
    public virtual ISet<Child> Children { set; get; }
    // Or so on...
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

IList

- Bidirectional Relation : **NOT SUPPORTED**. (since there is an additional index column that is introduced to maintain the order of the children, which the child element cannot sense)
- Ordered : Yes
- Type : IList
- Duplicates : Allowed
- On Adding an element : entire collection will be loaded to get the index column value. Avoid if the list of children is huge.

Bags

- Bidirectional Relation : Supported
- Ordered : NO
- Type : IList
- Duplicates : Allowed
- On Adding an element : only a single hit to the database. No performance issues.

ISet

- Bidirectional Relation : Supported
- Ordered : NO
- Type : ISet ( till NHibernate 3.0 it supported the interface from `Iesi.Collections`)
- Duplicates : **NOT ALLOWED**
- On Adding an element : entire collection will be loaded to check for duplicates. Avoid if the list of children is huge.

ICollection can be used as the type of the child collection which can be mapped by any of the three NHibernate Mappings

Nhibernate Cookbook 3.0 has a good explaination of using each of the collection , Just in case you happen to come across it.

Comment: I'd use `ICollection<T>` for bags. `IList<T>` implies that there is a order and an index which is not true for bags.

Comment: Would you expand on the IList not supporting bi-directional relationship. We have all of our collections exposed as  IEnumerable as property and IList as backing field, and we have NO issues with bi-directional relationships what so ever.

Answer (score 1):

Any IEnumerable implies deferred execution, so you want to use this in a query when your retrieval is going to be subject to further processing downstream (filtering being the most obvious scenario).

If that isn't the case, and indeed you want to make sure you don't enumerate the collection more than once, you would make it available as IList, ISet or ICollection. IList will be preferred when you want to ensure that the collection may have duplicates, whereas ISet is preferred when you want to ensure the set does not have dupes (set behavior being more useful in my experience).

Both IList and ISet *are* ICollections, which exposes bare bones collection behavior like Count. In an NHib context you might see this in implementations where Iesi collections are being used instead of a .net HashSet, but that likely has more to do with the fact that there was once no .net HashSet and then there was a lag in NHib's ability to use it easily (but NHib *would* be able to map ICollection to the Iesi set).

HTH

Comment: "Any IEnumerable means deferred execution" is not true. All collections are an IEnumerable. Nothing speaks against using IEnumerable properties for collections mapped as set or bag if you never need to modify the collection.

Comment: @cremor. technically true, but that would still be the primary reason to expose a collection as such, IMO. I changed the wording from 'means' to 'implies you want". Words *are* important :--)

Comment: @Berryl The name IEnumerable implies only that the thing it represents can be enumerated.
Deferred execution is supported by IEnumerable but it's by no means the only use case.
Just one fore example: infinite enumerables.